# ROS catkin_make error undefinend reference for a simple C program lib

Tags: ros

I'm trying to create a simple node which uses a simple C library (***libarithmetic.a***) which had been built outside the ROS framework.

trying to use the library ***add(...)*** function in my package node results in ***undefined reference*** error  .I assume i have missed something in the ***CMakeLists.txt*** which cannot figure out what exactly it is.

below are screenshots of my CMakeLists.txt and the catkin_make log messages

Thanks

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.2)
project(example_01)

add_compile_options(-std=c++11)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
)

catkin_package(
  #INCLUDE_DIRS include 
  #LIBRARIES example_01
  #CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs
  #DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
  include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  /home/hanoch/my_playfield/inc
)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}_node 
    src/example_01.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}_node
   ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
#  ${EXT_LIBRARY}
   /home/hanoch/my_playfield/lib/libarithmetic.a
)
```

the catkin_make result is

```
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable /home/hanoch/ros_workspaces/hanoch_ws/devel/lib/example_01/example_01_node
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/example_01_node.dir/src/example_01.cpp.o: in function `main':
example_01.cpp:(.text+0x4fe): undefined reference to `add(float, float)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [example_01/CMakeFiles/example_01_node.dir/build.make:102: /home/hanoch/ros_workspaces/hanoch_ws/devel/lib/example_01/example_01_node] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:418: example_01/CMakeFiles/example_01_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Comment: You should use `add_library` in your `CMakeLists.txt`. You can find more information about it [here](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html).